# 3 matchers expected, 4 recorded

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock

I get this exception during the mock recording time.
I tried searching for a solution in this forum and made sure that I did not mess up any another parameter.

The below mock expectation is giving the error.

```
EasyMock.expect(slotManager.addSlotPageletBinding(EasyMock.isA(String.class), EasyMock.isA(String.class), EasyMock.isA(helloWorld.class))).andReturn(true);
```

Before this statement I have another mock expectation on the same method with TWO parameters (overloaded method). Below is that mock.

```
EasyMock.expect(slotManager.addSlotPageletBinding(EasyMock.isA(String.class),EasyMock.isA(String.class))).andReturn(true).anyTimes();
```

Could any one guide me on this? Thanks.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 3 matchers expected, 4 recorded.
    at org.easymock.internal.ExpectedInvocation.createMissingMatchers(ExpectedInvocation.java:56)
    at org.easymock.internal.ExpectedInvocation.<init>(ExpectedInvocation.java:48)
    at org.easymock.internal.ExpectedInvocation.<init>(ExpectedInvocation.java:40)
    at org.easymock.internal.RecordState.invoke(RecordState.java:76)
    at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:38)
    at org.easymock.internal.ObjectMethodsFilter.invoke(ObjectMethodsFilter.java:72)
    at org.easymock.classextension.internal.ClassProxyFactory$1.intercept(ClassProxyFactory.java:79)
    at com.amazon.inca.application.SlotManager$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$3bf5ac02.addSlotPageletBinding(<generated>)
    at com.amazon.iris3.apps.Iris3YourAccountApplicationTest.testBuildIncaViewConfiguration(Iris3YourAccountApplicationTest.java:107)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:168)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:232)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:227)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550036/easymock-java-lang-illegalstateexception-1-matchers-expected-2-recorded mentions making sure to not create matchers after calling a replay, perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you recorded 3 expectations (calls) of your mock but while test executes there was 4 calls of mock's methods. So you've missed one call somewhere. Try to read more your code under test and discover missing call. Or use debugger to discover it.